# What's the best way to customise and view Amazon Web Service Usage reports?

Tags: xml, csv, amazon-web-services, usage-statistics

does anyone know the best tools to use to view amazon web service usage reports? I have downloaded previous reports as .csv and opened in Excel. I want to be able to generate custom reports with the data however and so think XML is a better bet and to use something like Altova XMLspy with a stylesheet to generate custom reports. Is there a way to do this with excel - create a template that will format the csv the way I need it each time?

thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 0):

Excel may be one way if you happen to find a ninja... Two products that does just that:
[CloudRows](http://www.cloudrows.com/) and [CloudSplit](http://www.cloudsplit.com/)

-Disclaimer: I'm a founder at CloudRows :)